# pd.read_excel with converters or dtype doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas

`pd.read_excel` with converters or dtype doesn't work.

```
a=pd.read_excel('/TMP/abc.xlsx', dtype=str)
```

`a['amount']` gives float values without `$` symbol. Even `converters={'amount':str}` doesn't give desired result.

Please suggest a way to retain the dollar symbol from Excel into pandas dataframe as string

Comment: Your Excel file probably doesn't actually have dollar signs in it; check whether it is formatted with the accounting preset.

Comment: Right.  This is another case where you are confusing the CONTENTS of the data with the PRESENTATION of the data.  Excel will add a $ when display a value if it is formatted as currency, but the cell does not contains the $.  Now you need to take your own steps to present the data in the way your users want to see it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I see it now. How about a percentage symbol. The data in the Excel has % but when loading into the dataframe, it shows values divided by 100.